# Android Intent Creation

Tags: android, object, android-context

Why should we include context object reference in the constructor while creating the Intent Object??

Example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context object,Target.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is required to determine the application package. Internally `Intent` creates an instance of [`android.content.ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html). While this can be achieved by specifying the package using a `String`, it is easier to just specify the context.

Comment: Thank you Malcolm. But why ComponentName will get instantiated while Intent creation??

Comment: @Nandu Because this is the class used to uniquely identify a component. Applications have unique packages, and there are various classes inside each application. Therefore, to identify the component, you need to know the package and its class. `ComponentName` is the class that contains both of them, thus fulfilling its purpose.

Comment: Thank you Malcolm. Then may i know the reason for also including the Context object in the creation of a view object programmatically?? Ex: TextView tv = new TextView(this);

Comment: @Nandu This is not really question-related, but I'll answer anyway: you need `Context` in the `View` because any `View` is tied to the particular application: it needs its resources, theme, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It is used [to initialize a field](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context,java.lang.Class%29) of type [`ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html), which in turn is used for routing purposes [across the whole API](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.0.3_r1@android%24content@ComponentName&type=type&k=u). Usage of `ComponentName` seems related to the [deepest (native) parts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html) of the Android platform